# kotlinx.serialization - Serialize ArrayList<Date> as data class variable with custom DateSerializer

Tags: android, serialization, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I need to serialize ArrayList as data class variable with custom DateSerializer,
with single date variable i use annotation:

```
@Serializable
      data class SearchBundle(
      @Serializable(with = DateSerializer::class) var startDate: Date? = null)
```

Somebody know how to do it for arrayList of dates?

Answer (score 8):

Probably easier then your current approach is to just specify the `DateSerializer` on file level of your `SearchBundle`-class via [`UseSerializers`-annotation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/custom_serializers.md#useserializers-annotation), e.g.:

```
@file:UseSerializers(DateSerializer::class)

import kotlinx.serialization.*
import java.util.*

@Serializable
data class SearchBundle(
        var startDate: List<Date>? = null)
```

That way you can keep your `DateSerializer` as is and the rest of your code just works, i.e. it will automatically use `DateSerializer` for all `Date`-types within that file.

Comment: An interesting solution, I did not know that you can assign a serializer at the file level, i will try, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Serializable
class TestDates(
    @Optional @Serializable(with = DatesArraySerializer::class) var dates: ArrayList<Date>? = null
)

object DatesArraySerializer : KSerializer<ArrayList<Date>> {

    override val descriptor = ArrayClassDesc(DateSerializer.descriptor)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, obj: ArrayList<Date>) {
        encoder.encodeSerializableValue(ArrayListSerializer(DateSerializer), obj)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): ArrayList<Date> {
        val dates = decoder.decodeSerializableValue(ArrayListSerializer(DateSerializer))

        return dates.toList() as ArrayList<Date>
    }
}
```